# I'd like to get some data from auth_user table on Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to get some data from auth_user table, but I only can get username.

views.py

```
from myapp.models import User2

result1 = User2.objects.filter(email="foobar@gmail.com")
print(result1)  # [<User: JohnLennon>]
result2 = User2.objects.filter(pk=1)
print(result2)  # [<User: JohnLennon>]
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User2(AbstractUser):
```

Using pdb, these don't work.

```
(Pdb)result1.id
(Pdb)result2.email
*** AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'email'
```

I can get data from another tables. Like,

views.py

```
rows = User_Profile.objects.filter(uid=1)
```

test.html

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.fname }} 
{% endfor %}
```

But, I can't do same way from auth_user table.
How can I get user's data from auth_user table like first_name and email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. it seems I was confused...

```
(Pdb) for i in result: i.email
'foobar@gmail.com'
```

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
result1 = User2.objects.filter(email="foobar@gmail.com")
```

A QuerySet List is created. `result1` is not a QuerySet object, so you cannot access attributes of the user by printing attrs of list.

Either you have to user `get()` method like this

```
result1 = User2.objects.get(email="foobar@gmail.com")
```

Or directly access the first object of the QuerySet List, like this:

```
result1 = User2.objects.filter(email="foobar@gmail.com")[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, v1k45. I could understand. Thank you.